# How to get Firefox to not paint its menu over my title bar?

Tags: firefox, context-menu, title-bar

To my great chagrin, I've been forced to start using Windows again after several years. I've installed Firefox, enabled the Menu bar, and I'm noticing that the menu bar gets printed over the title bar. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

To get the menu bar and the tile bar to co-exist:

1. Click on the "Open menu" icon. That's at the far right -- three horizontal bars.
2. Click `Customize...`.
3. Enable Menu Bar in the `Toolbars` dropdown, and check the checkbox for "Title Bar".

That should give you both the menu bar and the title bar.

Here are the items to toggle on the Customize screen:

[image: Items to check in the Customize screen]

And here is the end result:

[image]